# More efficient sort algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I'm looking for an algorithm, which could perform better, than `Arrays.sort()`.
I know this will look like a silly question asked million times, but please read on.

Let's have two classes implementing `Comparable` whose natural ordering is based on an int value. The first `compareTo` method looks like this:

```
 public int compareTo(ComparableInteger o) {
     return this.value - o.value;        
 }
```

The second is this:

```
public int compareTo(ComparableInteger o) {
    if (this.value > o.value) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        if (this.value == o.value) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

When I call `Collections.sort` on list of instances of these clases, they both perform about the same.

**My question is if there is a sorting algorithm, which would benefit of the added information of the first `compareTo` method.**
In the first example, the added information is this:

Let's have three values of `ComparableInteger`:

```
a == 1
b == 2
c == 3
```

Now when we compare `c` to `a`, we get 2 and when we compare `c` to `b` we get 1. From the `compareTo` implementation it is clear, that the `b` should go after `a`, because `c.compareTo(a) > c.compareTo(b)` so we know the correct order. The existing `Comparable` contract doesn't require this and needs another comparison. For example following implementation also fulfills(at least I hope) the contract, but gives different result(numbers sorted, but even numbers are before odd numbers)

```
public int compareTo(ComparableInteger o) {
    if (value % 2 == o.value % 2){
        return value - o.value;
    } else {
        if (value % 2 == 1){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

- I'm well aware that the first example is not sound, because the int may overflow

Comment: This is the kind of nano-optimization that is unlikely to matter.  I believe the algorithm underneath is quicksort.  I'll bet you can't measure a performance difference.

Comment: Interesting question. It reminds me of [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

Comment: Is this just curiosity, or have you profiled your code and came to the conclusion that the `sort(...)` method is a hot spot? Java's collections/array sorting algorithms are quick- and merge-sort, which both run in O(n*log(n)).  There are faster sorting algorithms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641858/linear-sorting-algorithms

Comment: It is just a curiosity. It always bugged me, that it doesn't matter if I return real difference or just `0/1/-1`

Comment: It does matter.  The subtraction is broken because it can overflow.

Comment: Just FYI, the V8 engine (the Javascript engine in Chrome and Node.js), the built-in sort is a hybrid quicksort/insertion that actually isn't very good. It's really, really, hard to beat a simple, straightforward heapsort for a standard library sort, and that's really what they should have used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of things which the efficiency of a sorting algorithm could depend on, but one thing to note is that in general, if you are sorting based on comparisons between elements, the fastest possible asymptotic runtime is `Ω(n lg n)`.

It is, however, possible to construct a scenario where sorting can be done faster than `n lg n`, but this requires using more information than just comparisons. These are the so-called "linear sorts", which sort by using the *value* of the element rather than a comparison to another element. Examples of these are Bucket Sort, Counting Sort, and Radix Sort.

The first comparison method you provided does provide extra information, which might enable a faster sort speed, but only under constrained conditions. If, for example, you know that there are *no duplicate values*, and that *every* value between the minimum and maximum value is used *exactly once*, then you could perform a sort by:

1. Performing a linear search to find the minimum.
2. Comparing each element to the minimum and placing at the index given by the comparison method.

This method should take `2n = O(n)` time. Of course, unless the objects contain extra information besides the integer value, you could just construct the range `min..max` directly. Also, if you can read the integer values of the elements, you could just implement a normal bucket or counting sort on them.

**tl;dr**: The fastest possible comparison based sort is `Ω(n lg n)`. It is possible to sort faster when you can read the exact value of an element, but  linear sorts are only work in certain constrained circumstances. In general you should just use your programming language's builtin sort.

Comment: Thanks!. I've tried radix sort on integers and it's about 2 times faster than `Collections.sort`. I'm just not sure if it's because of the algorithm or the objects overhead

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with the first Comparison, it is not perfectly consistent.

```
 public int compareTo(ComparableInteger o) {
     return this.value - o.value; //not always correct
 }
```

As [Eric Lippert points out](http://ericlippert.com/2011/01/31/bad-comparisons-part-three/) (the article is for C#, but still valid for Java), you first Comparison is unsafe:

> In particular, for the inputs Int32.MinValue and Int32.MaxValue, the
>   difference is 1. Clearly the smallest possible integer is smaller than
>   the largest possible integer, but this method gives the opposite
>   result!

As you mentioned, other overflow/underflow problems arise as well.

So in fact, it would take more logical overhead outside the comparison for any sorting algorithm to try to use the "extra" information.  The "extra" information comes at the cost of some extra headaches and corner cases.

Comment: It's unsafe in more corner cases... if I do `Integer.MAX_VALUE - any negative int`, then it will overflow.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj thanks.  I made the wording more general.

Comment: But I've already mentioned that in the original post. I don't think that changes a lot about the question. It could be BigInteger...

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj Like I mentioned, the "extra" information comes with the price of having to deal with the overflow/underflow problems.  You'd have to keep your datatypes' size in mind and do extra logic to prevent the overflow/underflows for every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the extra information in the first `compareTo` is as useful as you think: in your example, you have merely replaced a comparison between objects with a comparison between *results* of `compareTo`, and that will be the case regardless of sorting algorithm.

Comment: Looks like you're right. It could be only benefitial if the `compareTo` was expensive.

Answer (score 1):

- Normal algorithm: 3 comparisons
- Your algorithm: 2 comparisons + 1 comparison of 'cached' values of previous differences. (in your example checking that 2>1 which will determine order of `a` and `b`)

As for `O` complexity they are the same, but my feeling is that your implementation will be bit slower in practice (and bit harder to implement).

Comment: I see that now. It would be best to create a method `getIntValue` and sort based on that instead of `compareTo`. I really didn't think this through :)

Answer (score 0):

Always stick with the core Java Collection features such as `Arrays.sort()` as they have been tested for all kinds of nuances that have been noted in the answers so far, that most programmers aren't likely to think of, and they are also tuned for performance.  And when the next version of Java comes out, you won't have to re-test your own sort routine.