# In Java, why is comparing two elements of relatively time consuming

Tags: java, sorting

So I am on a program that uses, insertion sort, selection sort, and merge sort. I time all the programs and make a table on which are the fastest. I understand why merge sort is more efficient than selection sort and insertion sort(b/c of the effectiveness of comparing elements).

My question is why does comparing elements of an array relatively consuming and why does it make insertion and selection sort less efficient.

Note : I am new to java and couldn't find anything on this topic. Thx for your responses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [More efficient sort algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369149/more-efficient-sort-algorithm)

Comment: Or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234711/which-sorting-algorithm-works-best-on-very-large-data-set)

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't what I was looking for. Should I explain my question more thoroughly?

Comment: A single comparison doesn't take long at all, but when you compare *many* elements in a large array or collection, then it makes sense that this will take time. How much will depend on the efficiency of the sorting algorithm and the structure of the data.

Comment: Hi @JoeyForte, please have a look [here](https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/) for algorithm efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is why comparing 2 elements of an array relatively consuming ....

Relative to what?

In fact, the time taken to compare two instances of some class depends on how the `compareTo` or `compare` method is implemented.  However comparison is typically expensive because of the *nature* of the computation.

For example, if you have to compare two strings that are equal (but different objects), you have to compare each character in one string with the corresponding character in the other one.  For strings of length M, that is M character comparisons plus the overheads of looping over the characters.  (Obviously, the comparison is cheaper in other cases .... depending on how different the strings are, for example.)

> and why does it make insertion and selection sort less efficient.

The reason that insertion and selection sort are slower (for large datasets) is because they do *more* comparisons than other more complicated algorithms.  Given a dataset with N elements:

- The number of comparisons for quicksort and similar is proportional to `N * logN`
- The number of comparisons for insertion sort and similar is proportional to `N * N`.

As N gets bigger `N * N` gets bigger than `N * log N` *irrespective of the constants of proportionality*.

Assuming that the datasets and element classes are the same, if you do more comparisons, that takes more CPU time.

---

The other thing to note is that the number of comparisons performed by a sort algorithm is typically proportional to other CPU overheads of the algorithm.  That means that it is typically *safe* (though not mathematically sound) to use the comparison count as a proxy for the overall complexity of a sort algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

> why comparing 2 elements of an array relatively consuming

As asked in Stephen C's answer, relative to what?

Selection sort and insertion sort have time complexity O(n^2), while merge sort has time complexity O(n log(n)), so for reasonably large n, merge sort will be faster, but not because of compare overhead compared to the O(n^2) sorts.

For merge sort on an optimizing compiler, where compared elements are loaded into registers (assuming the elements fit in registers), then the compare overhead is small since the move will will write the value that was loaded into a register rather than read it from memory again.

As for compare overhead, if sorting an array of primitives, indexing is used to access the primitives, but if sorting an array of objects, which is usually implemented as an array of pointers to objects, the compare overhead is increased due to dereferencing of pointers. This would impact a comparison of quick sort versus merge sort (more moves, fewer compares), but the issue with merge sort versus insertion sort or selection sort is the O(n^2) time complexity versus merge sort O(n log(n)) time complexity.

In the case of sorting an array of objects, there's also the issue of sorting the pointers versus sorting the objects, which is a cache locality issue. Depending on object size, it may be better to sort the objects rather than sort the pointers, but this isn't really related to compare overhead as asked in the original question.